# Objective C: Uploading and downloading from a server

Tags: objective-c, ios

What's the easiest way to retrieve text and upload text to a server? And how would I create files from the app on the server?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the easiest way to read text from an http endpoint on a web server is:

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.apple.com"];
NSString *content = [NSString stringWithContentsOfURL:url encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];
```

to save text, i would use a simple rest based xml web service where i would post the text data to this service and read the appropriate response back to know if the operation was successful

Comment: Also if you prefer JSON you could look into SBJsonParser which allows easy coversion from JSON to NSDictionary.